# How can i update state in nested contexts in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am nesting multiple contexts in React Native and React Navigation V5. My issue is when i log the user, i want child Context to consume parent contexts state. but when i import a property from context which is supposed to have been updated it return null.

```
          <AuthProvider>
            <AuthContext.Consumer>
              {authContext => {
                if(authContext.loading) return <View/>

                return <ProductsProvider>
                        <ProductsContext.Consumer>
                          {productsContext => {
                            return (
                            <NavigationContainer>
                              <Stack.Navigator
                                screenOptions={{
                                  initialRoute: "Home"
                                }}
                              >
                              {authContext.token ? (<>
                                  <Stack.Screen 
                                    name="Home" 
                                    component={Products}
                                   /></>):
                                 ( <>
                                    <Stack.Screen 
                                      name="Login" 
                                      component={Login}
                                /></>)}...
```

then in my Products provider after successfully dispatching token to state.. i get token of null

```
export const ProductsProvider = ({children}) => {
    let [ productsState, dispatch ] = React.useReducer(ProductsReducer, initialState);
    let { token } = React.useContext(AuthContext);
    console.log(token)
...
```

How can i recify this. i'm only getting a state update after refreshing the application.